# Global const char pointer array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have defined a const char pointer array in header file. Array contains multiple strings. Now I have to find a string at particular index. I don't know how should I access this array from another files. Please see my code:

common.h

```
extern const char *lookup_str[] = {"test Str0", "test Str1", "test Str2", "test Str3"};
```

file1.cpp

```
int ret = 3;
std::string r = lookup_str[ret];
```

Can I use this way in all my C files? Let me know if you can see any alternative approach. Any suggestion/help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Why are you using `std::string` in c?

Comment: `extern` is for declarations, not definitions. You need to pick one .c/.cpp file for `const char* lookup_str[] = { ... };` (the definition) and in the header, you just have `extern const char* lookup_str[];` (the declaration).

Comment: Sorry. My bad. that is c++ file.

Comment: What are you asking? Can you have an extern const char * in a header? Yes. Is it a good idea? No.

Comment: Thanks @jforberg. could you please tell me any alternative way to achieve this thing?

Comment: @Rock26:
In your .h file:
extern const char *lookup_str[];

In ONE of your C-files:
const char *lookup_str[] = {... values };

Comment: That's C++, not C! They are **different** languages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable without initializing it in the .h file:

```
extern const char *lookup_str[];
```

Initialize it in exactly one source file.

```
const char *lookup_str[] = {"test Str0", "test Str1", "test Str2", "test Str3"};
```

To use it in a .cpp file, use:

```
#include "common.h"

...

int ret = 3;
std::string r = lookup_str[ret];
```

---

A better alternative, IMO, would be to provide a purely functional interface to the data.

The .h file:

```
std::string const& lookup_str(size_t index);
```

The .cpp file:

```
std::string const& lookup_str(size_t index)
{
   static std::vector<std::string> str = {"test Str0", "test Str1", "test Str2", "test Str3"};
   return str.at(index);  // This will throw exception if index is not
                          // within bounds.
}
```

and then use it as:

```
#include "common.h"

...

size_t ret = 3;
std::string r = lookup_str(ret);
```

**Update**

A C++98 implementation of `lookup_str()` would be:

```
std::string const& lookup_str(size_t index)
{
   static std::vector<std::string> str;
   if ( str.empty() )
   {
      str.push_back("test Str0");
      str.push_back("test Str1");
      str.push_back("test Str2");
      str.push_back("test Str3");
   }
   return str.at(index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @R Sahu. I tried your approach but I got this error: "error: in C++98 'str' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'". This is production environment and I am not allowed to change anything.

Comment: @Rock26 then you need to tag your question 'C++98'.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid having variable definitions in header files. Instead, you can have a *declaration*, which simply informs the compiler of a symbol, which can be defined elsewhere, and compiled separately.

So, your header should look like this:

```
extern const char *lookup_str[]; // defined elsewhere
```

And you should add this to a source (.c) file (doesn't matter which one, as long as it's linked into the final executable):

```
const char *lookup_str[] = { ... };
```

Then to use it, simply include the aforementioned header, and use it like you would any array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing this in `c++`, dont do it with `c-strings`, do it the c++ way:

*common.cpp*

```
std::array<std::string, 4> lookup_str = {"test Str0", "test Str1", "test Str2", "test Str3"};
```

*common.h*

```
extern std::array<std::string, 4> lookup_str;
```

Then you can use it in the same way:

```
int ret = 3;
std::string r = lookup_str[ret];
```

Or in awesome c++ ways:

```
auto stringInArr = std::find(lookup_str.begin(), lookup_str.end(), "test Str3");
```

Here is a live example:

http://ideone.com/UFfIyV

Answer (score -1):

A cleaner design IMO would be to declare the extern and definition in a header file separated by macro definition

**strdef.h**

```
#ifdef STRING_INSTANCE_DEFINE
const char *lookup_str[] = {"test Str0", "test Str1", "test Str2", "test Str3"};
#else
extern const char *lookup_str[];
#endif
```

**strdef.c**

```
#define STRING_INSTANCE_DEFINE
#include <strdef.h>
```

**All other files**

```
#include <strdef.h>
```

Remeber to define the macro **STRING_INSTANCE_DEFINE** only in 1 **.c** file. All other files using the array could simply include the header file and it would be available to them as extern.

Comment: A precompiler macro definition is not scoped to the c file where you define it. This will depend on ordering and won't work in general.